# mysql flush tables with read lock verification

Tags: mysql

this seems like a dumb question and perhaps I'm not googling this correctly but I'm trying to figure out what the table status or database status should show after I issue:

```
flush tables with read lock;
```

I was hoping that my script could capture that output somehow.

It's a standalone server so 'show master status' doesn't work.

Comment: You have to create a verification. Do you want me to post an answer to that effect ?

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe there is a verification for this. The only real way to do this is to test an insert into a table. That insert should wait until the lock is released before it is committed.

thanks.